# command-line arguments for postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.4, psql

The following database restore command is failing because of `too many command-line arguments (first is "151019_testbase.sql")`. This is effected from a shell session within the directory of the application (I initially had it calling the backup file from a subdirectory `_private/151019_testbase.sql` but changing that does not alter the behaviour.

```
pg_restore -c -1 -v v4_development 151019_testbase.sql
```

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgrestore.html) has examples where multiple options are set `pg_restore -C -d postgres db.dump`, so that's not it (apparently). 
*Note, this attempt is with option 1 (one) for running a single BEGIN/COMMIT*

I do not see the source of the error.

I also attempted to issue the command running `psql v4_development` first (to also chef on previous state) and postgresql returns `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_restore"`

Comment: To run a `.sql` script you need to use `psql`.  `pg_restore` is only needed to restore dumps taken in the "custom format"

Comment: If your `.sql` file happens to be something that `pg_restore` can really consume (see @a_horse_with_no_name's comment), then try adding `-d` before the database name, like in your example.  (I suppose `v4_development` is your database.)

Comment: @deszo yes `v4_development` is the database. Yes the dump was obtained via custom format `pg_dump -Fc`.  I am confused as to which shell I should be issuing the command, the bash shell or that after identifying with `psql v4_development`?

Comment: the `-d` option was the necessary element  `pg_restore -c -v -1 -d v4_development _private/151019_testbase.sql` runs now